# For setting limit in multiline edittext 's each line

Tags: android, xml

I want to set limits in `edittext` each line and then click `enter` key cursor move to the next line in android studio, please answer how can I do this..my codes are

```
<EditText
      android:inputType="textMultiLine|number"
      android:singleLine="false"
      android:digits= "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
      android:id="@+id/number"
      android:hint="Enter Number Here..."
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:textSize="15sp"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:gravity="top|left"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="130dp" />
```

when I click `enter` key it did not work and when I remove `inputType` from `XML` code enter key works please solve

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps below:

#### Step 1: add these lines in your `XML`

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

#### Step 2(optional): use following code in your `Activity`

If you want to do some action when user clicks `next`

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
        //your code here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I m using `AndroidX` with `Java 1_8` enabled

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use `android:minEms` or `android:maxEms`. Read more in following link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText